# Stream to a file in ruby when exporting a large database table to a csv file

Tags: ruby, csv, file-io, mysql2

I export the following from a mysql database using a little ruby script and the mysql2 gem

```
require 'csv'
require 'mysql2'

begin
    db = Mysql2::Client.new( :host => ".", :username => "xyz", :password => 'xyz', :database => 'xyz')

    results = db.query 'select * from mytable'

    CSV.open("C:/tmp/mytable.csv", "w") do |csv|
        csv << results.fields

        results.each do |row|
            csv << row.values
        end
    end
end
```

This works fine for small tables but I think I should be doing things differently for big tables.  I could be wrong here but it seems to read the entire table out to memory and then write it all in one go.  If i've got a huge table with tens of millions of rows I'd like to stream to the file constantly.

How would I go about doing that?

I tried running this against a table with ~10 million rows and got the following

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

---

I've found [this](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#streaming), will report back if it works

```
result = client.query("SELECT * FROM really_big_Table", :stream => true)
```

Comment: Is the problem with reading from the database, or with writing to a CSV file, or both?

Comment: Good question, I'll check in the morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was indeed this, the problem was reading the database table

```
results = db.query( 'select * from mytable',  :stream => true, :cache_rows => false )
```

The writing of the csv was done asynchronously

Answer (score 2):

This isn't perhaps the Ruby solution you are looking for, but it is *one* solution:

MySQL supports direct output to a CSV file. In your case if all you need is a CSV dump, then the most efficient way is probably to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
  INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\tmp\\mytable.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

This works if the MySQL server is on the same computer as the output file, since it will be the server that writes the file, not the client.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Comment: Nice solution but unfortunately I'm working remotely to the server and don't have direct access, only a login